# Search a user in multiple systems through WSO2 ESB proxy

Tags: proxy, wso2, esb

I need to send just one request (can be a proxy url) which takes user id as input and call multiple endpoints and return the response after aggregating all of them.

Currently I am using a proxy service implementation to achieve it but is returns just one response(can be from any of the endpoints) and not able to combine responses from other systems/endpoints. Though I can see the response from another endpoint in my server console.

Below is the code I implemented so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="ProxyTestTwoW"
       transports="http,https"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log/>
         <clone>
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <property name="Application" value="Application1"/>
                  <property name="messageType"
                            value="application/xacml+json"
                            scope="axis2"
                            type="STRING"/>
                  <property name="Authorization"
                            expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('username:password'))"
                            scope="transport"/>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint>
                        <address uri="localhost:8080/iiq/rest/identities/9000070"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </sequence>
            </target>
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <property name="Application" value="Application2"/>
                  <property name="messageType"
                            value="application/xacml+json"
                            scope="axis2"
                            type="STRING"/>
                  <property name="Authorization"
                            expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('username:password'))"
                            scope="transport"/>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://localhost:8080/iiq/rest/identities/9000071"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </clone>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full" description="">
            <property name="Component" expression="get-property('Application')"/>
         </log>
         <aggregate>
            <completeCondition>
               <messageCount min="2"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete expression="$body/*[1]">
               <property name="messageType"
                         value="application/xacml+json"
                         scope="axis2"
                         type="STRING"
                         description="messageType"/>
               <send/>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <log level="full" category="WARN"/>
      </faultSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Result :
**After hitting proxy URL in browser:** - Only one response as below:

```
<jsonObject><viewableIdentityAttributes><Email>Kevin.Mollo@companyb.com</Email><cn>Kevin Mollo</cn><Last Name>Mollo</Last Name><First Name>Kevin</First Name></viewableIdentityAttributes><listAttributes>First Name</listAttributes><listAttributes>Last Name</listAttributes><listAttributes>Email</listAttributes><listAttributes>cn</listAttributes></jsonObject>
```

**In server logs:**

```
[2016-07-14 11:46:35,057]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addr
essing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:3beaaf16-7b94-4e
08-a3e0-7605869572c7, Direction: response, Component = Application1, Payload: {"vi
ewableIdentityAttributes":{"Email":"Kevin.Mollo@companyb.com","cn":"Kevin Mollo"
,"Last Name":"Mollo","First Name":"Kevin"},"assignedRoles":[],"listAttributes":[
"First Name","Last Name","Email","cn"]}
[2016-07-14 11:46:35,057]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addr
essing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:c878c7db-ad4c-49
46-94d6-75aebc75ad8e, Direction: response, Component = Application1, Payload: {"vi
ewableIdentityAttributes":{"Email":"Michelle.Lassauze@companyb.com","cn":"Michel
le Lassauze","Last Name":"Lassauze","First Name":"Michelle"},"assignedRoles":[],
"listAttributes":["First Name","Last Name","Email","cn"]}
```

As we can see I get responses from both the endpoints in server logs.

As per analysis, I feel to make it work properly and get the responses from both the endpoints, we need change the following:
1.  Using call mediator instead of send if we have multiple endpoints to be called.
2.  Using enrich mediator to store the responses.

I tried following the above approaches but I am unable to get the expected results as I am not sure how to use enrich mediator in this case.

Please help me in fixing the above issues.

Comment: You have two different independent problems. Ideally you should post these as two questions. Regarding combining the responses, iterator mediator is the way to go as per given information. 

There might be a problem with the way you aggregate. Could you add sample responses from two services with complete message body etc. as an edit to the question?

Comment: Please add two question with clear details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Clone mediator will be used to send identical copies of message to different endpoints.
- Iterate mediator will be used to send message chunks of one particular message to different endpoints.
- Enrich mediator will be used to change message (Ex: removing content, adding etc.) [1]

Check your endpoints and check whether they provide proper responses to work with aggregate mediator.

I add sample scenario here. You can test that with your ESB pack to understand the above three mediators usage. You just have to start 2 instances of SimpleStockQuote service [2] and publish message to proxy via SOAPUI.

```
<proxy name="ScatterGatherProxy" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable" transports="https http">
    <description/>
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <clone>
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <send>
                            <endpoint name="vendorA">
                                <address uri="http://localhost:9001/services/SimpleStockQuoteService/"/>
                            </endpoint>
                        </send>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <send>
                            <endpoint name="vendorB">
                                <address uri="http://localhost:9002/services/SimpleStockQuoteService/"/>
                            </endpoint>
                        </send>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </clone>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <aggregate>
                <completeCondition>
                    <messageCount min="2"/>
                </completeCondition>
                <onComplete expression="//m0:return"
                    xmlns:m0="http://services.samples" xmlns:m1="http://services.samples/xsd">
                    <enrich>
                        <source clone="true" xpath="//m0:return[not(preceding-sibling::m0:return/m1:last &lt;= m1:last) and not(following-sibling::m0:return/m1:last &lt; m1:last)]"/>
                        <target type="body"/>
                    </enrich>
                    <send/>
                </onComplete>
            </aggregate>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

If you need further assistance, please attach more details like responses of your service.

[1] http://dilshanilive.blogspot.com/2016/03/enrich-mediator-wso2-esb.html

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Setting+Up+the+ESB+Samples#Starting%20the%20Axis2%20server

Comment: Thank you.I get response from both the endpoints.But it returns xml data:<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><viewableIdentityAttributes><Email>Kevin.M@companyb.com</Email><Name>Kevin</Name></viewableIdentityAttributes></jsonObject><soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><viewableIdentityAttributes><Email>Miele.Lass@b.com</Email><Name>Miele</Name></viewableIdentityAttributes></jsonObject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
I need the response in JSON format.

Comment: You can use XSLT mediator. Refer sample scenario :https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sample+440%3A+Converting+JSON+to+XML+Using+XSLT

Comment: I tried using XSLT but it doesn't work. I still get the response in soap xml format. I guess the issue is with the below line in xpath expression : 
   <enrich>
                  <source clone="true" xpath="/"/>
                  <target type="body"/>
               </enrich>
What changes should I make to get JSON response for the response xml like below:
{"viewableIdentityAttributes":{"Email":"Kevin.Mollo@companyb.com","cn":"Kevin Mollo","Last Name":"Mollo","First Name":"Kevin"},"assignedRoles":[],"listAttributes":["First Name","Last Name","Email","cn"]} plus all JSON responses.